# How to write standard output in hexadecimal of a pointer address using write()

Tags: c, pointers, hex

In a task I need to print the address of a pointer in hexadecimal into the standard output. The issue is that I am only allowed to include `unistd.h` so no `printf` is allowed.

I have tried to cast it into a char* but the cast is quite impossible to achieve. So help would be so appreciated in here.

It should print something like that:

```
000000010a161f40
```

Comment: cast into a long long int then use division by 16 and a table to print hex numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've coded a `print_pointer` function that does the exact same thing as `printf("%p",pointer)`

```
#include <unistd.h>

void print_pointer(const void *p)
{
    static const char *table = "0123456789abcdef";
   unsigned long long value = (unsigned long long)p;
   // 1 digit = 4 bits
   char buffer[sizeof(void*)*2];
   int i,idx = 0;
   
   while(value)
   {
       int digit = value % 16;
       buffer[idx++] = table[digit];
       
       value /= 16;
   }
   // zero-padding
   for (i=idx;i<sizeof(buffer);i++)
   {
       buffer[i] = '0';
   }
   // reversed print, as division computes lowest digits first
   for (i=sizeof(buffer)-1;i>=0;i--)
   {
       write(1,buffer+i,1); // write 1 char to standard output
   }
   
    
}

int main()
{
    const char *data = "foo";
    
    print_pointer(data);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to reverse the buffer if the buffer was instead population from the end to the front.

Comment: you're totally correct since padding makes it fixed to 16 digits. My first version didn't have padding, which explains the reverse stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a function that does just that :

```c
#include <unistd.h> // Prototype of write()

size_t my_putchar(char c) // Function for writing to standard output
{
    if (write(1, &c, 1) == -1)
        return (0); // Returns 0 because no char has been written
    return (1); // Returns 1 because a char has been written
}

size_t my_puthex(unsigned long long nb, short toUp)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    const char *base = (toUp == 1) ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef"; // If toUp is 1, the letters will be displayed in uppercase, otherwise in lowercase.
    if (nb < 16) { // If the number is less than 16, simply write the corresponding char by calling `putchar()`
        len += my_putchar(base[nb]);
        return (len);
    } else { // Recursively call the puthex() function to write the characters 1 by 1.
        len += my_puthex(nb / 16, toUp);
        len += my_bputchar(base[nb % 16]);
    }
    return (len); // Returns the number of chars written
}
```

Usage :

```c
my_puthex(1724, 0); // Write 1724 in hexadecimal in lower case
my_puthex(1724, 1); // Write 1724 in hexadecimal in upper case
```

Output:

```bash
6bc
6BC
```

However, the input value must be an unsigned integer.
You can also replace `toUp` with a bool if you can include `<stdbool.h>`.

Comment: good solution. Some explanations would be interesting, though. 1) recursion to invert the direction of the digits, 2) write(1) to write to standard output, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Then there's this:

```
void ptr2hex( const void *ptr ) {
    unsigned long long val = (unsigned long long)ptr;
    char buf[ 2 * sizeof ptr ];
    size_t i = sizeof buf;

    for( ; i; val >>= 4 )
        buf[ --i ] = "0123456789abcdef"[ val & 0xF ];

    write( 1, buf, sizeof buf );
}

int main( void ) {
    ptr2hex( "" );

    return 0;
}
```

In brief, the size of a `long long` is 8 bytes, translating to 16 ASCII digits. `i` is assigned to be twice the 8 bytes. A buffer of that size appears and is filled, from its *end* to its *beginning*, with 16 ASCII digits in a loop. (Leading zeros come from the same source with a tiny bit more exercise for the processor.) Then, simply output those digits in order with a single `write()`.

Three variables, one loop, and no recursion.

Obliged to @chux for pointing out some code tweaks.